# jQuery Showing an Ajax loader during transmission & Prevent Multiple Submits

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I have an app that has several different types of form elements which all post data to the server with jQuery AJAX.

**What I want to do is:**

1. Show a loader during AJAX transmission
2. Prevent the user from submitting twice+ *(clicking a lot)*

This is easy to do on a one off basis for every type of form on the site (comments, file upload, etc). But I'm curious to learn if that is a more global way to handle this?

Something that's smart enough to say:

1. If a form is submitting to the server and waiting for a response, ignore all submits
2. Show a `DISABLED` class on the submitted / clicked item
3. Show a loading class on the `class="spinner"` which is closest to the submit item clicked

What do you think? Good idea? Done before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQuery Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

In a nutshell, you can set events which occur on *each and every* AJAX request, hence the name **Global Event Handlers**. There are a few different events, I'll use `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete()` in my code sample below.

The idea is that we show the loading, disable the form & button on the `ajaxStart()` event, then reenable the form and hide the loading element inside the `ajaxComplete()` event.

```
var $form = $("form");
$form.ajaxStart(function() {
     
    // show loading
    $("#loading", this).show();

    // Add class of disabled to form element
    $(this).addClass("disabled");

    // Disable button
    $("input[type=submit]", this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```

**And the AJAX complete event**

```
$form.ajaxComplete(function() {

    // hide loading
    $("#loading", this).hide();

    // Remove disabled class
    $(this).removeClass("disabled");

    // Re-enable button
    $("input[type=submit]", this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

You might need to attach to the `ajaxError` event as well in case an AJAX call fails since you might need to clean up some of the elements. Test it out and see what happens on a failed AJAX request.

**P.S.** If you're calling `$.ajax` or similar (`$.getJSON`), you can still set these events via `$.ajaxStart` and `$.ajaxComplete` since the AJAX isn't attached to any element. You'll need to rearrange the code a little though since you won't have access to `$(this)`.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you have to do 2 for sure and 3 to improve usability of your app. It is better to keep backend dumb but if you have a security issue you should handle that too.